# Rocky Linux dns port

Tags: dns, redhat-enterprise-linux

I recently changed the default dns port from 53 to 54 in /etc/named.conf and enabled the DNS service to listen to that very port with this command :

```bash
firewalld-cmd —permanent —zone=public —add-port=54/udp
```

But it seems the firewall is blocked with semanage.
Does anyone have an idea about how to get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

SELinux is a security architecture for Linux systems which allows administrators to take manager access of the system.

This command will probably help you solve your issue:

```
semanage port -a -t dns_port_t -p udp/tcp <new_port>
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help. My load balancing is now working as you can see below :

Comment: Really appreciated your help It worked! 172.30.0.254 is my virtual IP address used by nginx  and it is redirected on the real IP address of my node on the normal port 53 :          
State      Recv-Q     Send-Q           Local Address:Port            Peer Address:Port     Process
UNCONN     0          0                      0.0.0.0:53                   0.0.0.0:*
UNCONN     0          0                     10.0.0.1:54                   0.0.0.0:*
UNCONN     0          0                 172.30.0.253:54                   0.0.0.0:*